# Nothing happens when the button is clicked (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I am trying to code a game in Android Studio. I run the apk but buttons does nothing.

When 'oyna' (means play) or 'ayarlar'(means settings) button is clicked, gamesettings or settings class should run but nothing happens. Briefly, buttons doesn't respond. What can i do ?

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button settings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
assert play != null;
assert settings != null;
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settings);
            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameSettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@mipmap/anasayfa3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="283dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="283dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="388dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings_button"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="244dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="296dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add ` android:text="Play"` you maybe clic in the other buttom

Comment: no button works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your button has been set **invisible** in your xml.

Just remember, **INVISIBLE views don't receive touch events**.
However there are a few alternatives you can use if you really want your button to be invisible and still reacts to touch event.

- Set the view's alpha to 0. This would make it fully transparent and it'll still listen to click/touch events.
- Put a touch handler on the parent and check if the touch is in the area of the invisible view

First one is easier to do.